# filling out a pandas dataframe with a json-like field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a dataset with two columns 'type' and 'waveforms',
'Type' will contain a comment like 'real' or 'simulated'
'waveforms' will contain a object created from a JSON file. A single entry in the 'waveforms' column will look like the exemplar below. Also, the number of rows is more than 100.

```py
{'waveformId': 'simulated',
 'sensorId': 'NA',
 'lastModifiedDateTime': 'NA',
 'sampleStartDateTime': 'NA',
 'sampleStartNanoSec': 'NA',
 'sampleDurNanoSec': 'NA',
 'sampleRateHz': 'NA',
 'detectionDateTime': 'NA',
 'detectionNanoSec': 'NA',
 'peakAmplitude': 'NA',
 'gain': 'NA',
 'posThreshold': 'NA',
 'negThreshold': 0,
 'maxRateOfRiseTime': 'NA',
 'samples': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...,511],
 'negRateOfRiseTime': 'NA'}
```

I can create the data frame with the first column completed and the second column with just a header.

I repeated an example that filled 'waveforms' with nan.

How the dataframe looks:
[image: link to how the dataframe looks]

How do I add rows to the dataframe that contain this exemplar. I will fill the 'samples' field with other values that I make up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to use JSON as the data type for the `waveforms` column. Were you not able to simply set the value to a dictionary using something like `df.at[idx, 'waveforms'] = my_dict`?

Comment: That's exactly what I found that just worked. Thank you for answering. I saw your response afterward. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
question_df.at[row_number,'waveforms'] = exemplar